# Disable differences in login handling (non-interactive, interactive etc.)

Tags: login, command-line, ruby, session, rvm

I'm always having trouble with [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) installs and non-interactive vs. interactive shell sessions. If the session isn't interactive I'm usually getting the `command not found` error on different programs/functions in the RVM/Ruby toolchain (i.e. `gem`, `rvm`, `ruby` etc.). There are three solutions to the issue I'm aware of:

- Add/remove some lines from `.bashrc` for each user. The changes depend on the version of Ubuntu
- Typing `bash --login` before working with RVM to get a interactive shell
- Changing the 'Run command as login shell' option in gnome-terminal

All those solutions aren't exactly what I'm looking for because I have a couple of hosts with different versions of Ubuntu and for some applications the solutions outlined above don't work (i.e. daemonized [Chef configuration management suite](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home)). As far as I could trace the problem down this is based on the fact that shell scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are only run if the user logs into a interactive shell session. Which seems not to be the case if a daemonized process runs or if I or an application logs in trough ssh.

What I'm basically searching for is a way to unify all different kinds of shell sessions to execute scripts in `/etc/profile.d`. Ideally this solution should work for all users that are able to login, and for different versions of Ubuntu (atm in use: 10.4, 11.10). It would also be good if it could be easily be set up using automated scripts or Chef recipes.

As a note: I don't know if not-running scripts in `/etc/profile.d` is the sole problem I'm facing, I know tough that doing a `bash --login` usually fixes my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is gnome-terminal not using `--login` for bash by default:
https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

For scripting with RVM choose one of the methods described here: https://rvm.io/integration/cron/

There is more information on user rc files here:
https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login

Comment: In which way does this help? All informations you posted seem to be already mentioned in my question, don't they?

Comment: the first link shows you how to enable the login shell in gnome-terminal ... I should be more clear about it

Comment: gnome-terminal doesn't work for processes running on a non-graphical server environment, ssh logins etc. I already knew both links you provided and they don't apply to my problem. The solutions outlined work for one type of login (graphical). I'm updating my question accordingly.

Comment: @PizzaPill check the man page of ssh => `ssh — OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)`, as for using RVM in demonized scripts/cron - you should not use login shell there, it's dangerous, check this ticket for whenever: https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/216#issuecomment-4336716 .

Comment: I don't want to use the login shell, I just want to use RVM. Do you have a working solution for ssh, demonized scripts/cron, bash sessions and ubuntu 10.4-11.10 which is easy to distribute via scripts? Thats what I'm searching for.

Comment: since I'm getting the feeling that I don't get my point across, here is a scenario: Assume you have 1 Million hosts of Ubuntu 10.4-11.10 with 1000 local users (each) that have random accountnames and you want to enable each user (including root) to use RVM over ssh, bash, gnome-terminal or cron/scripts. How would you do that?

Comment: ok so any terminal (GUI or ssh) should be a login session - it's what you do when open those, so those will make use of interactive RVM.  For scripting you should not use interactive RVM loaded ahead (globally via system), there is description on how to use RVM in scripting/cron https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/cron/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2777/discussion-between-pizzapill-and-mpapis)